# CCButton not working while touchMoved Implemented

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, cocos2d-x, ccsprite, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have to place functionality where CCButton can be dragged to proper position, wherever user needs to place them.

I have create a custom class for this but the issue is `click` method of the button is not being called when user clicks on the button.

`touchyButton.h`

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "cocos2d-ui.h"

@interface touchyButton : CCButton { ... }
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL touchMoved;
@end
```

`touchyButton.m`

```
#import "touchyButton.h"


@implementation touchyButton

- (void) touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchMoved...", nil);
    self.touchMoved = YES;
    self.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];
    //CGPoint inTouchLoc = [self convertToNodeSpace:self.anchorPoint];
    //CGPoint touchP = ccpAdd(touchLoc, inTouchLoc);
    //self.position = [self.parent convertToNodeSpace: touchP];
    self.position = touchLoc;
}

- (void) touchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.touchMoved = NO;
    NSLog(@"touchEnded...", nil);
}

@end
```

As the code explains, we are just trying to move the button wherever on the screen when user drags on the button.

Calling of the button in main code where it needs to be displayed.

```
        touchyButton *btnRight = [touchyButton buttonWithTitle: @"" spriteFrame:[[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed: @"arrR.png"] spriteFrame]];
        [btnRight setBackgroundOpacity:0.5f forState: CCControlStateNormal];
        [btnRight setAnchorPoint: ccp(1, 0.5)];
        [btnRight setPosition: ccp(viewS.width - 10.f, viewS.height/2)];
        [self addChild: btnRight];
        [btnRight setTarget:self selector: @selector(performRightJump:)];
```

Now, when user clicks on the button, the button goes into selected state but `performRightJump` never fires. Can anyone suggest any alternative how I can implement the button with dragging behaviour with target action working..? Any hint would be appreciated as well.

One more thing is, in current code I can only be able to move the button's anchor point to the new touch point. Any idea how I can move the button in real fashion? The current method causes problem of tapping of first time for move, button's anchor point jumps to the tapped point.

Comment: I am unable to solve this and need to terminate the question.

Comment: Unable to resolve the issue and left its development.

Answer (score 1):

this code is cocos2dx but useful for you

> create a new class classA and classB

add this code 
classA.h

```
{
//here implement 
 CC_SYNTHESIZE_RETAIN(classB *, _ classB, _ ClassB);
}
```

classA.cpp

```
bool classA::init()
{
set_classB(classB::initwithclass());
   this->addChild(get_ClassB(),0);


//here create button
   return true;


}
bool classA:: onTouchBegan (Touch *touch ,Event *event)
{

_classB->setposition(touchLoc); 
  return true;
}
void classA:: onTouchMoved(Touch *touch, Event *event)
{
}
void classA:: onTouchEnded(Touch *touch ,Event *event)
{


}
//as well as this code use in cocos2d
```

Comment: I will try the code this week and let you know the answer. You have not given any clarification for Class A and Class B. Class A should be CCButton? And what should be in Class B? By the way thanks for your response.

Comment: classA-implement  CCButton and classB is moveable class, you are change a  classB  position according to   touch loction .

Comment: @Himandhu-kalal: thanks Himanshu. I will check on this this week and will let you know.